# get-content | select-string -pattern creates more line breaks?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

this is a very weird issue. I try to do simple "grep" - meaning filter lines containing some string from a file and output it into another file.
Very weirdly the lines int the output file are broken based on the powershell window size! Why the heck?

```
gc bigfile.csv|select-string -pattern "September"|out-file september.txt
```

for example line

"982390","102201","Microsoft September 2021 Security Updates","MSS-OAR-something","Windows Server 2012 R2","Windows Server 2012 R2;N/A","Nearshore-Windows-Sweden-Group-2","server21","Not Installed",,,,,"5005563;5005613;5005627"

has line break here
"Windo

ws Server

if I change the window size, it makes the line break somewhere else.
I just want to select the lines, not put more line breaks there! It behaves the same in ISE or powershell. How to make it work correctly?

Comment: `gc ... |Select-String ... |ForEach-Object Line |Out-File ...`

Comment: yes this workaround is working. Thanks. But it's not very simple and doesn't explain why  this is happening. If I pipe something from one command to another how can it be affected by the size of the window?? I think this is a bug which needs to be fixed by MS

Comment: Piping arbitrary objects to `Out-File` makes it try to render the output as it would in the console and output the result to file. It can be annoying, for sure, but it's working as designed

Comment: actually it doesn't work sorry - the original line breaks from the source file are lost alltogether this way.

Comment: "the original line breaks from the source file" are lost as soon as you use `gc`/`Get-Content`. Does your actual regex pattern attempt to match across multiple lines?

Comment: They are not lost. Why would they be? They are in the resulting Out-file, BUT along with new ones which I don't want. Not sure what you mean by regex. I search for a word September. I actually tried not piping GC into select-string but just used select-string filename -pattern|Out-file and that works but adds filename line number: on each line unfortunately